# How to use the Lua Editor Plugin in Eclipse Rcp Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, lua, eclipse-rcp

When i installed Lua using Install new software in Eclipse Luna and  Neon (http://download.eclipse.org/ldt/releases/stable) totally 24 plugins included in plugins directory including org.eclipse.ldk.ui. After this Lua operations are working in both eclipse Luna and Neon. Then i added all these 24 plugins in Rcp product file and launched the Rcp application.But while editing lua files i am getting error like
No Validator found for test.lua file
Unable  to find grammer

But the same .lua files are working fine with eclipse luna/neon
How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Greg, I am trying in eclipse 3.x application

Comment: Deleted the tag